# How to access a database on mySQL on Windows Server 2012

Tags: mysql, windows, apache, server

I have no idea how Windows Server works. All I want to do is gain access to a database in mySQL on Windows Server. Is there a phpmyadmin like there is on Cpanel? I have no idea where to go.

It's a Windows Server 2012 that runs Apache and mySQL on which Wordpress is installed.

Someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, for accessing mysql databases in a windows app, I use HeidiSQL.. But we don't do recommendations for software on SO, so you're free to choose whatever you want and I'm not going to focus on particular software in this answer

To access the mysql instance you'll need to know the username and password of a user with sufficient privileges to do what you want. If you don't know this username/password, a good place to sart looking is in the config files of any apps (like your apache web apps, wordpress etc) that use the db and see if you can read the password out in plain text there.. With luck the person who set all this up will have left behind the username/password in a config file and yu're away. If your question is about how to break into a database where you don't know the password, make an edit so this is more clear

Comment: HeidiSQL it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might check to see if PHPMyAdmin or MySQL workbench is installed; both are great tools for managing MySQL databases and popular with Wordpress developers

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. Yes the server happened to have HeidiSQL installed on it and I was able to access the database.

Thanks for your help.